# UITableView error iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, uistoryboard

I am new to iOS development so I am probably missing something simple but I am getting a strange error when I try to load a viewcontroller with a tableview in it. So far I have a login screen that upon successful login then performs a segue to a viewcontroller that should display a list pulled from a json call.

The error is this:

```
NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "uAc-LO-hfA-view-W70-kC-rzJ" nib but didn't get a UITableView.
```

I am using a tutorial to learn this stuff so I am wondering if I did something wrong when I set up the viewcontroller.

tutorial link - http://dadabeatnik.wordpress.com/2013/11/01/parsing-json-in-ios/

Comment: Does your xib have a tableview in it ? Is it set as the view ?

Comment: Is the tableview embedded in your uiviewcontroller? If so, are you referencing it using outlets?

Comment: that is what is strange to me, I am using storyboards so I dont see a xib file. When I created the Viewcontroller I just drug a tableview into it so I would guess it's embedded. But there is code that fills the cells with the JSON data so I was thinking maybe that is where the issue lies. The only outlets I have are : view - view , datasource - Table View , delegate  - Table View

Comment: Make a outlet of your tableview and try adding this [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"] in viewDidLoad()

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your JSON parsing. This error is related to your storyboard.

Suggestion:
Take IBOutlet UITableView *table and connect to your tableview. I think your problem will resolve.

Comment: So control drag from the Table View Cell to the Table View? When I do that it asks for accessoryView, backgroundview, editingAccesoryView and selectedBackgroundView

Comment: I was asking about table view.